# Pod install fails with "LoadError - cannot load such file -- earlgrey"

Tags: cocoapods, integration-testing, earlgrey

I followed the instructions as verbatim on https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/blob/master/docs/install-and-run.md#cocoapods-installation and I when I run pod install, I get:

```
LoadError - cannot load such file -- earlgrey
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EarlGrey` uses the the `earlgrey` gem in order to download any Swift or CocoaPods dependencies as stated here in [the doc](https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/blob/master/docs/install-and-run.md#step-2-add-earlgrey-as-a-framework-dependency). It seems like the gem wasn't installed correctly.

Remember that gems are installed in `/usr/local/bin`, which you might need to provide access to. To do so, do `sudo gem install earlgrey` or `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin` and you should be ready to go!

Answer (score 2):

I'm running exactly the same issue and I couldn't fix it using `sudo gem install earlgrey` or `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin`. I couldn't find any solution yet - fix doesn't work because of latest update to macOS Sierra (just guessing)?

```
LoadError - cannot load such file -- earlgrey
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

@edit:
Found a solution. 
1. Download and place `configure_earlgrey.rb` file in the same folder where yours `Podfile` is. 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/EarlGrey/master/gem/lib/earlgrey/configure_earlgrey.rb 
2. Replace `require 'earlgrey'` with `load 'configure_earlgrey.rb'` in `post_install` part inside `Podfile`. 
3. Do `pod install` again.

Comment: This solutions eschews the earlgrey gem. Have you noticed this issue only after upgrading to MacOS Sierra?

Comment: Is the EarlGrey Gem saved in your gems directory?

Comment: I didn't try it before Sierra so I can't tell sadly. Obviously yes, I've tried installing earlgrey gem without and with sudo, verifying that it's in gem dir.

Comment: And it came up in `gem list earlgrey`, but you weren't able to read it in the docs?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct.
```*** LOCAL GEMS ***
earlgrey (0.0.13)```

Answer (score 1):

sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

Then

arch -x86_64 pod install